# Javascript async in nested for loop MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, async.js

I have an asynchronous function inside a for loop nested in another for loop.

```
// recipesArray is an array of arrays of objects
// recipeObject is an array of objects
// currentRecipe is an object

connectToDb(function(){
   // LOOP 1
   for (var i=0, l=recipesArray.length; i < l; i++) {
      // recipeObject is an 
      var recipeObject = recipesArray[i];

      // LOOP 2
      for (var x=0, y=recipeObject.length; x < y; x++) {
         var currentRecipe = recipeObject[x];

         // this is an asynchronous function
         checkRecipe(currentRecipe, function (theRecipe) {
            if (theRecipe === undefined) {
               console.log('RECIPE NOT FOUND');
            } else {
               console.log('RECIPE FOUND', theRecipe);
            }
         });
      }
   }
});
```

I need to add data to the recipesArray based on the results of the checkRecipe function.

I've been trying different things... 
- do i try to keep track of i and x...
- do i try to have multiple callbacks...
- do i even need to do all of that, or is there some other way....

I also tried using the async library for node(which actually has been very helpful with other situations), but the forEach doesn't take objects(only an array).

Stuck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say that `forEach` only works on arrays, but you *have* only arrays? Or at least `recipesArray` and `recipeObject` both look very array-like.

Comment: Um, those objects are passed as arguments to your callback function? Maybe show us the code you've tried.

Comment: If I pass something like this into the async.forEach:
[{
   color: red,
   size: med
}]

I wont get access to color and size in the each function.

Comment: @Bergi, I think this is the issue I'm running into: https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/26

Comment: But you're not passing the object, but the array that contains the object? `async.forEach([{color:"red", size:"med"}], function(obj, cb) { console.log(obj.color, obj.size); checkRecipe(obj, cb); })`

Comment: If you really needed to enumerate an object (your current code does not do it anywhere, `LOOP 2` is an array iteration as well?), you could still use `Object.keys()` instead. Edit: [Here it's even mentioned in the duplicate of the bug you linked](https://github.com/caolan/async/pull/168#issuecomment-38011802)

Comment: I have tried Object.keys(), and I can pass the correct data into the checkRecipe function.

But, now how do I edit the original object with the results of the function. Do I need to keep track of i and x to know which array of array of objects key value i need to edit in recipesArray?

Comment: try not to "edit" the original object, but rather use `map` instead of `each`. And yes, `i` and `x` are automatically kept for you in the closure when you use a callback.

Comment: with the testing I've done, it appears that i or x goes much faster than the async function.

So, if the async callback runs, how would i edit recipesArray[i][x].

I literally just need to add a true or false to each object.

recipesArray
[[{ key: value},
{key: value}],
[{key: value},
{key: value}],
[{ key: value},
{key: value}],
[{key: value},
{key: value}]
]

Comment: @Bergi, can you explain what you mean by don't edit the original object.

Comment: Please [edit] the code you've tried with `async.js` into your question so that I can refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `checkRecipe()` can be run in parallel with no limits, here's how you might use `async.each()`:

```
connectToDb(function() {
  async.each(recipesArray, function(subArray, callback) {
    async.each(subArray, function(currentRecipe, callback2) {
      checkRecipe(currentRecipe, function(theRecipe) {
        if (theRecipe === undefined)
          return callback2(new Error('Recipe not found'));
        callback2();
      });
    }, callback);
  }, function(err) {
    if (err)
      return console.error('Error: ' + err);

    // success, all recipes found
  });
});
```

Comment: So then what does (a small example of) `recipesArray` look like?

Comment: [{ color: red, size: med }, { color: green, size: large }]

Comment: Ok, then you don't actually have an array of arrays then. You just have an array of objects. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, I said that wrong(wrong array).

The recipesArray looks like
[
 [
   { key: value,
     key: value,
     key: value
   },
   {key value.....
   },
   {...
   }
],
[{},{},{}]
]

Comment: an array of arrays of objects

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51558/discussion-between-mscdex-and-joel)

Comment: This code is great and works well for iterating through the items, but I still don't have the answer I'm looking for: "I need to add data to the recipesArray based on the results of the checkRecipe function."

In a regular for loop, I could keep track of the index. As far as I can tell, this async loop does not allow for this, so how would i go back and edit the original array recipesArray[i][x]?